# Unfortunately MusicPlayerApp has Stopped

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-debugging

Please help my app crashes this is my logcat

```
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
06-18 05:03:10.800 10304-10304/com.example.vikram.musicplayer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10304 SIG: 9
06-18 05:03:21.908 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.vikram.musicplayer
06-18 05:03:21.916 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
06-18 05:03:21.919 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.vikram.musicplayer
06-18 05:03:21.919 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
06-18 05:03:21.948 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.vikram.musicplayer
06-18 05:03:21.949 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
06-18 05:03:21.960 11965-11979/com.example.vikram.musicplayer I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
06-18 05:03:21.963 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-18 05:03:21.964 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.vikram.musicplayer, PID: 11965
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vikram.musicplayer/com.example.vikram.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2195)
            at com.example.vikram.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
06-18 05:03:24.033 11965-11965/com.example.vikram.musicplayer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11965 SIG: 9
```

Comment: add your xml code for the activity and also format your logcat properly. its still plain text here

Comment: Share your relevant code also, to find out and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per your logcat, you need to redefine you ListView id. Try this -

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Since you are using ListActivity your xml file must specify the keyword android while mentioning to a ID.

Hope it will help :)